# Sorting filenames with a number of '-' delimiters

Tags: sort

I want to sort a set of files with the same number of '-' delimiters in each filename (with -n for numeric sorting).

Here is an example list

```
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-01.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-02.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-03.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-04.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-05.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-06.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-07.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-08.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-09.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-10.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-11.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-12.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-13.png
```

Here is the code I am using

```
for fl in "$@"; do
   fnme=${fl##*/}
   ftyp=${fl##*.}

   fdir=${fl%/*}
   fnam=${fnme%.*}

   nf=$( echo "$fnam" | awk -F '-' '{print NF}')
   ifld=$(( nf + 1 ))

   find "$fdir" -type f -name "${fnam}-*.png" |
     awk -F'[-.]' '{print $(NF-1), $0}' RS='\0' ORS='\0' |
     sort -znt '-' -k "$ifld"n | 
   while IFS= read -r flimg
   do
     echo "$flimg"
   done
done
```

But when I try with the first three files being-1, -2, -3, the result is still not sorted numerically

```
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-04.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-05.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-06.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-07.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-08.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-09.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-10.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-11.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-12.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-13.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-1.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-2.png
/home/flora/edvart/docs/schimmel-3.png
```

Comment: The number of dashes are always the same, but could be different on a different set of filenames.

Comment: `find | sort -z` won't work. Either use `find -print0` or remove the `-z`. And if you're staying with the `-z` you need to read NULL-delimited lines in your `while read` with `read -d ''`. Although to be honest just replacing that loop entirely with `tr '\0' '\n` would be better

Comment: I did `find "$fdir" -type f -name "${fnam}-*.png" -print0 | sort -znt '-' -k "$ifld"n  |` and using `while IFS= read -d '' flimg`, but got the same output as before. I think the `sort -k` tries also to pick the `.png` part.

Comment: Try a version sort (which is what GNU sort calls a natural sort) instead of a numeric sort.  i.e. `-V` rather than `-n`.   Also, as mentioned by @roaima, use `-print0` if you're going to use `sort -z`.  Given that you're working with arbitrary filenames, I would not recommend relying on newlines as the delimiter - NUL-separated is the right way to do it.

Comment: I have introdiuced `-print0` now.

Comment: With `-V`, I still get `schimmel-3.png` last.

Answer (score 2):

The `zsh` shell has a shell option called `NUMERIC_GLOB_SORT`.  It makes globbing patterns sort numerically by default.

From a non-`zsh` shell:

```bsh
zsh -o NUMERIC_GLOB_SORT -c 'printf "%s\n" /home/flora/edvart/docs/*.png'
```

or, using the `(n)` glob qualifier to enable this shell option only for the given pattern,

```bsh
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" /home/flora/edvart/docs/*.png(n)'
```

Or, passing the pattern as an argument rather than hard-coding it in the `zsh -c` script.  Note that the pattern needs to be quoted.

```bsh
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" ${~1}(n)' zsh '/home/flora/edvart/docs/*.png'
```

Testing:

```
$ ls -d *.png
schimmel-04.png   schimmel-08.png   schimmel-11.png   schimmel-3.png
schimmel-05.png   schimmel-09.png   schimmel-12.png
schimmel-06.png   schimmel-1.png    schimmel-13.png
schimmel-07.png   schimmel-10.png   schimmel-2.png
```

```
$ zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" ${~1}(n)' zsh '*.png'
schimmel-1.png
schimmel-2.png
schimmel-3.png
schimmel-04.png
schimmel-05.png
schimmel-06.png
schimmel-07.png
schimmel-08.png
schimmel-09.png
schimmel-10.png
schimmel-11.png
schimmel-12.png
schimmel-13.png
```

If you have further numbers in your directory path, this would still work given that the numbers in the directory path are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be easier to manipulate the file list with `sed` to capture the last field *and add it at the beginning*:

```
sed -e 's/^.*-\([^-]*\)\.[^.]*/\1-&/g'
```

Now you can sort based on the *first* field of the fake "filename", and after sorting, you can remove the extra data using `cut` skipping the first field.

```
cut -f2- -d-
```

So:

```
ls | sed | sort | cut
```

## Example

I created this small directory and touched some zero-length files in it:

```
Oct 17 01:06 .
Oct 17 01:06 ..
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-001.png
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-002.png
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-12.png
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-17.png
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-356.png
Oct 17 01:06 201-ventosa-title-91.png
Oct 17 01:06 333-ventosa-longer-title-this-time-77.jpg

ls | sed -e 's/^.*-\([^-]*\)\.[^.]*/\1-&/g' | sort -rn | cut -f2- -d-
```

gives, as expected,

```
201-ventosa-title-356.png
201-ventosa-title-91.png
333-ventosa-longer-title-this-time-77.jpg
201-ventosa-title-17.png
201-ventosa-title-12.png
201-ventosa-title-002.png
201-ventosa-title-001.png
```

(Removing the "r" option from sort reverses the order).

Note that the "77" element gets positioned correctly even if the number is in a different field.

Comment: My primary need in to handle normal numbering as well, when I have -1, -2, -3, ... -356 rather than the straightforward -001, -002, ..., -356 sequence.

Comment: Then the `-n` option of `sort` is your friend (interprets fields numerically rather that lexicographically).

Comment: Have used `sort -znt '-' -k "$ifld"n` but still got the fie listing to start from the double digits.

Comment: I must confess I am not familiar with all those options of `sort`. I can say that this solution works as required with `sort -n`. I have added the example.

Comment: `-k` defines the field to sort on, with delimiter defined by `-t '-'`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem originated because I was using mawk 1.3.3-17. Release 1.3.4 or later can use \0 as a record separator with the meaning "null character". Older releases of mawk, BSD awk, Busybox awk, Plan 9 awk etc. all treat the string `\0` in `RS` as if `RS` had been the empty string, i.e. it enables "paragraph mode" (double newlines delimit records).